# port 3306 not available in mysql server configuration

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, port

I am trying to configure MySQL server to use port 3306, Normally this is the default port, but I cant seem to select it. I have tried finding any processes that might be running on the port and i have yet to find anything. i have tried reinstalling MySQL server, i have tried starting and stopping previous MySQL services that may still be running on that port. I have tried using port 3307, but i believe this is giving me an error when i try to install WordPress(which is what i ultimately want to do). Any information is appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: what does `netstat -apn`say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by checking the running processes on port 3306 using netstat -aon | more. Killed the task with Taskkill /PID then reconfigured MySQL server and port 3306 was available.